# print list of time using a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code have if statement where it only print the time after the time now,

http://jsfiddle.net/bvz0opy9/

```
var today = false;  
var d = new Date(),
    till = new Date(),
    t, h, m;

if (today) {
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 15 - d.getMinutes() % 15, 0, 0);
    till.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    till.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    while (d <= till) {
        h = d.getHours();
        m = d.getMinutes();
        t = h % 12;
        t = t == 0 ? 12 : t;
        $('#time').append('<li>' + (t < 10 ? '0' : '') + t + ':' + (m < 10 ? '0' : '') + m + ' ' + (h < 12 || h == 24 ? 'AM' : 'PM') + '</li>');
        d.setMinutes(m + 15);
    }
} else {
    // print full list of time with interval of 15 min
    // do it here
}
```

what if I want to get the full list of time? means from 12AM to 11PM with interval of 15 min. I can't understand some part of the code so I can't continue there, I do not want to use another loop to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript setHours function to set var d to 12am which is hour 0. the parameters for setHours is `(hour, [minute], [second], [milisecond])`. the '[]' part is optional.

delete this

```
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 15 - d.getMinutes() % 15, 0, 0);
```

change to

```
d.setHours(0,0,0);
```

Comment: how to do it within the else's scope?